# DDD persisting aggregate on 2 different databases

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I have a Generic `IRepository<T>` which gets implemented under `Infrastructure.NHibernate` Using `Simple Injector` to inject the implementation into the interface. `IRepository<T>` lives in my `Domain` so that the domain objects can use the repository which was injected.

I have a ``` User``AggregateRoot ``` which holds some detail about the user in the application database, `Id`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`. I know not to care about persistence, but this at stage we are talking about how these objects are persisted.

In my `Web.UI`(ASP.Net MVC 5) I have a screen where I can update the user details, `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Email`, `Address`. Id is stored but can't be updated.

When I update the `User` details, I use the `IRepository<User>` to update `Firstname` and `Lastname`.

Problem: I need to update the `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Email`, `Address` in our `OpenLdap` server too.

I have an `Infrastructure.Ldap` project where all the Ldap implementations etc sits. (repositories, services, entities, helpers, converters).

What is the best approach to update the LDap server?

Do I create another `ISomeRepository` Interface in the `Domain` which `Infrastructure.Ldap` implements? This will mean I need to add additional attributes to the `User` and just override the ORM Mapping to ignore additional attributes. I then use the `IRepository`, followed by `ISomeRepository` to update the user in both databases.

Or

Web.UI is already an infrastructure concern, so I just reference the `Infrastructure.Ldap` project and talk to the ldap repository directly which will work with a `LDapUser` object. This will let me update the User on Ldap separately.

I'm very confused, business rules are that we need to update user details. I assume from a DDD perspective, all the details that needs to be updated needs to live in the domain. how do I persist this `User` on 2 different data stores?

Is one of my options above valid and pass good practice, or is there perhaps a different solution? The business requires there to be the 2 different data stores, therefore I need to make this work.

`Id`, `Firstname`, `Lastname` - this is stored in the application database in case Ldap goes down and will be used for auditing purposes later on.

`Id`, `Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Email`, `Address` - this is stored in the `OpenLdap` server part of user administration.

Can someone please point me into the right direction please. Its really hard to think of this case strictly from a DDD perspective due to he constraints of where persistence needs to happen. If it was all on the application database, it would have been easy.

Comment: Would it matter if one of the two storage mechanism wasn't updated in a single ACID transaction? Could you update the DB and then raise an event that will eventually update LDAP or vice-versa?

Comment: Both needs to be updated at the same time, It would be Application DB, then Ldap. The User on Ldap can live on multiple application servers. So if they log out, and sign on to a different server, those details need to have pulled across, because on sign in we check the user details after authentication and update the application DB with what is in Ldap

Comment: If your repository abstraction is composable, you can use `Composite` pattern that invokes SQL repository implementation and also LDAP repository implementation. Then in `SimpleInjector` you should register `IRepository<User>` as a composition of `SqlUserRepository` and `LdapUserRepository`

Comment: I'm using fluentnhibernate with postgresql and my lap is a custom service implementation which uses a repository as well. Would u mind posting an answer with an example? My repository is abstracted into infrastructure.

Comment: @ArkadiuszK - I did some research and looks like a viable solution. If you can post an answer with a bit of detail I can accept that for you. The idea is to write 2 implementations of `IRepository` then tell simplinjector to `RegisterCollection` I think and that will call both the repos one after another I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Composite` design pattern with your repositories :

```cs
public IRepository<T>
{
    void Save(T entity);
}

public class CompositeRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IRepository<T>> repositories;

    public CompositeRepository(IEnumerable<IRepository<T>> repositories)
    {
        if(repositories == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repositories");
        }
        this.repository = repositories;
    }

    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        foreach(var repository in repositories)
        {
            repository.Save(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Let's assume that there exists `SqlUserRepository` and `LdapUserRepository` and both implements `IRepository<User>`. Then you can register `CompositeUserRepository` using container:

```cs
container.RegisterCollection<IRepository<User>>(new[] { typeof(SqlUserRepository), 
                                                         typeof(LdapUserRepository) });
container.Register<IRepository<User>, CompositeRepository<User>>();
```

Thanks to that your services further use `IRepository<User>` and they don't have to change when you add persisting `User` to `LDAP`. We also achieved nice side effect of that way solving this problem - `Single Responsibility` principle in context of repositories.